# Parse a POST request from Object to JSON

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to make a POST request to a server but I have an issue with Angular.
It seems that the server receive the request but I still see an error in the Console suggesting to change the body from Object to JSON

> error: SyntaxError: **Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse** () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69142:51)
> text: "A new user it was saved with id = : 23"
> **proto**: Object
> headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
> message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8191/api/user"
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"

In my cod for example I need to resolve this because I try to navigate to another page when I submit it.

```
createNewUser(user: User): Observable<Object>{
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.createURL}`,user);
  }

  saveNewUser(){
    this.userService.createNewUser(this.user).subscribe( data =>{
      console.log(data);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/list-user');
    },
    error => console.log(error));
  }
```

**Solution for an older Angular version where it had @angular/http**
In the past for an older version of Angular, older then 10, I know that I was able to do it like below but now is not RequestOptions I can not import it because it need @angular/http:

```
addUser(user: User){
        let body = JSON.stringify(user);
        //pass the content type which is aoolication/JSON cintent
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        //pass body and options
        return this._httpService.post("https://localhost:8443/api/user", body, options);
    }
```

Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the server is returning a text as a response. The response type in Angular HttpClient by default is `json`. You could set it to `text` in the request.

Try the following

```js
addUser(user: User){
  let body = JSON.stringify(user);
  let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  let options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers,
    responseType: 'text'     // <-- set response type as `text`
  });

  return this._httpService.post("https://localhost:8443/api/user", body, options);
}
```

#### Update: New version

You could pass the option directly in the request

```html
createNewUser(user: User): Observable<Object>{
  return this.httpClient.post(`${this.createURL}`, user, { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

Comment: addUser() is an solution from an older Angular version where I was able to import @angular/http now I am using createNewUser() with httpClient where in addUser() _httpService: Http

Comment: I misread the question. I've updated the answer. Please see if it works.